# PHP - test if a variable is an integer while allowing ".0" decimals

Tags: php

I want to check if number is numeric. `ctype_digit()` is a good function but I want `2.0` to return true and `2.1` to return false.

```
var_dump(ctype_digit(1)); // true

var_dump(ctype_digit(1.0)); // false - I want true

var_dump(ctype_digit(1.1)); // false
```

Comment: Please read the manual  : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Comment: just use is_numeric then

Comment: `ctype_digit` tests whether ***strings*** contain only number characters. You don't have strings here, you've got ints and floats, which by definition are numeric. Where exactly do those values come from and what might they possibly actually be?

Comment: Dont use `ctype_digit` which works for string and your getting into float why so?

Comment: If an answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether a variable represents an integer, while allowing `0` decimals, you can use:

```
floor($number) == $number
```

Examples:

```
floor(1) == 1 // true
floor(1.0) == 1.0 // true
floor(1.1) == 1.1 // false
```

Note that instead of [`floor($number)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) (round down), you could use [`ceil($number)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) (round up), or [`round($number)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) (round to the nearest integer).

Comment: I like your answer more than mine. ;)

Comment: Or you could use is_int, is_float or is_numeric as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Not as easy as one would think, here is my way of doing it.

```
$numbers = array(1.0, '2', 2.1, '2.1');

foreach($numbers as $number){
    $numberArray = explode('.', $number);
    if($numberArray[1] == 0){
        echo $number . '<br>';
    }
}
```